# JSF inputText and inputSecret differ in size

Tags: jsf, user-input, textinput

again just a short one:

I've done a login page in JSF which contains an inputText for the username
and a inputSecret for the password. Size is set to 20 for both.

FF manages to show it correctly, IE shows them in different sizes.
Is there a way to make them look similar in both?

rgds,

```
           KB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could show us the code snippet of these two inputs...
The best way to define the size of these elements is to use CSS classes:

```
.myInput {
    width: 60px;
}
```

and then use this class in the JSF components:

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="myInput"/>
...
<h:inputSecret ... styleClass="myInput"/>
```